# IDM Connected but Not Downloading File

Tags: windows-10, download-manager

I am Downloading a 2.1GB file using Internet Download Manager, and that is downloaded nearly 76%, but for some reason i paused the download, and after that its not resuming, "Resume Capability was and is YES".
It show "Send GET" and then shows receiving data, but not a single bit is going to be received.

I refreshed the download address several times, but of No use. I tried to download the same file with a different name and download get started, why can not I resume that same as its almost 76% completed , and that's too much.
Someone suggest if something can help in resuming that file.

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at will?  Is it only happening with a specific server, or is it every server you try?  How long did you leave it sitting after attempting to resume, before giving up?  You're image shows a very large file, so I'm thinking that the server may have been reading over it to get to the proper resume point before it started sending again. With a huge file, and a busy serer, that may take many seconds to perhaps even minutes, and the data being received may have just been keep-awake bits to keep the connection alive while it was preparing the file resume. Just a guess..

Comment: This happened with only this file, and after resuming i waited enough and idm popped out that unable to resume, Try again, but the same.
I guess i don't have any other option than restart download from begining